# JSON data property with quotation mark in value

Tags: javascript, json

Is it possible to have JSON like the example below? My JSON library is unable to handle this, I know it matches up the quotation marks which causes the error. So my real question is how can I fix this? I need to store javascript functions in my JSON. For example button = (javascript and html code for a button)

```
controls: {
    "button": "just "html" code for a button"
}
```

I have quotation marks in the values and please don't suggest to remove the quotation marks as that won't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the quotation marks like so:

```
    var controls = {
         "button": "just \"html\" code for a button"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, just need to escape `"`    by adding a `\` before it, like so:

```js
var controls = {
    "button": "just \"html\" code for a button"
};
console.log(controls.button);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes instead to enclose your data and property names.

```
var controls = {
    'button': 'just "html" code for a button'
};
```

Or you can simply escape the quotation marks, if you wish using backslash (`\`), e.g. `"button": "just \"html\" code for a button"`.

I personally always use single quotes in my JavaScript (as per the first example) to avoid such issues and I think it's cleaner syntax, but the choice is yours :)

**NB Answer given refers to the JavaScript notation given in your initial question version. If you're going to change the notation to JSON, then you should escape the quotes.**

Comment: That's invalid JSON.

Comment: It is invalid JSON. However, the code in the question looks like a JavaScript literal and not JSON. It's a badly written question.

Comment: On second thought, I agree :-)

Comment: It's not JSON. It's a JavaScript object declaration. And this is perfectly valid.

Comment: Could you please explain why its a bad question in more detail, so that I can learn.

Comment: @user5581557: Your question isn't about JSON, it's about writing string literals in Javascript. JSON is a way to encode data as text that is inspired by Javascript literals, but it's not exactly the same. And a Google search for "double quote in javascript string" would have given you an answer, so you didn't do basic research.